# chain rule using trig functions

Tags: derivatives

So I have the following:

$$
y = cos(a^3 + x^3)
$$

This is what I got.

$$
y' = \cos(a^3 + x^3) \ ( -sin(a^3 + x^3) ) \ ( 3a^2 + 3x^2 )
$$

I'm not sure what to do after this? Would this be the final answer?

Comment: You started off with $y=\cos(a^2 + x^3)$ but when you took the derivative, it became $a^3$ in the $-\sin(...)$ part.

Comment: First, the factor of $ \ \cos (a^2 + x^3) \  $ should not be there, since that is what you have differentiated.  Second, in most of these expressions, letters from the beginning of the alphabet, such as $ \ a, b, c , ... \ $ represent unspecified _constants_, so their derivatives are zero.

Comment: sorry the a and x should be $x^3 a^3$

Comment: @RecklessReckoner thanks! the unspecified constants helped me see what i was doing wrong.

Comment: This is a notational convention that students innocently stumble over at some point.  When I teach "Calc I", I make a point of explaining about "unspecified constants" in formulas and expressions, because otherwise I get asked what to do about the "other variable" $ \ a \ . $

Answer (score 1):

$$d[\cos(a^3+x^3)]=-\sin(a^3+x^3)d(a^3+x^3)=-\sin(a^3+x^3)3x^2dx$$

assuming $a$ is a constant and $x$ is the variable.  If you want to explicitly use the chain rule then let

$$u=a^3+x^3,\frac{du}{dx}=3x^2$$
$$y=\cos u,\frac{dy}{du}=-\sin u$$
$$\frac{dy}{dx}=\frac{du}{dx}\times\frac{dy}{du}=-3x^2\sin(a^3+x^3)$$

Answer (score 0):

What you wrote is not correct.  Assuming $x$ is the variable, the correct answer is 
$y' = -\sin(a^2+x^3)3x^2$

Comment: how did you get $3x^2$

Comment: @Mr.1.0 The chain rule.

Comment: does that come from $3a^2 + 3x^3$

Comment: @Mr.1.0 What?  No.  The derivative of $a^2 + x^3$ is $3x^2$.

Answer (score 0):

There is a wrong cosine function, a mistake (probably misspelling) in the argument of sine and a mistake in the third multiplier.
Is $y'$ equal to $\dfrac{\text d y}{\text d x}$? And $a$ is a constant or function?

Comment: what do you mean by wrong cos function because this is the original problem here http://i.imgur.com/ZEm6Yda.png

Comment: **sas** was referring to the $ \ a^2 \ $ you had in the argument of the sine function, which you have since corrected.

Comment: I am not clear, excuse me. You have a cosine function, yes, but when you differentiate it? $(\cos x)'$ isn't a $-\cos x \cdot \sin x$, it's just $-\sin x$.